# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "dürfen" und "können"?

Tags: modal-verb

In einer Übung habe ich das folgende bemerkt:

> Sie dürfen im Haus nicht rauchen
>
> _____ ich dann auf dem Balkon rauchen?

Ich habe es mit "kann" ausgefüllt, aber das Buch sagt "darf". Ich verstehe, dass "darf" besser wäre, aber meiner Meinung nach "kann" passt auch ziemlich gut. Oder gibt es einen Grund, wofür "kann" nicht geeignet wäre?

Comment: Discussed in English here https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11446/whats-the-difference-between-darf-and-kann/11451#11451 and pretty much answerable by a dictionary.

Comment: Wenn der erste Satz geheißen hätte: Sie können im Haus nicht rauchen. Wäre die Antwort wohl: Kann ich dann auf dem Balkon rauchen? gewesen. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In der Umgangssprache sind beide Versionen mittlerweile möglich und gebräuchlich. Es gibt dennoch einen [Unterschied](https://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,20593).

Strenggenommen fragt *darf* nach der Erlaubnis etwas zu tun, während *kann* danach fragt, ob man dazu in der Lage ist. Richtig ist in der Aufgabe also tatsächlich "darf", denn es wird nach der Erlaubnis gefragt.

Dazu folgende Beispiele

> "Kann ich morgen auf die Party?" "Nein, du hast die Grippe und bist bettlägerig." - Person ist körperlich nicht in der Lage
>
> "Darf ich morgen auf die Party?" "Nein, du hast Hausarrest." - Person hat nicht die Erlaubnis

Wie schon oben geschrieben fragt *kann* in der Umgangssprache (und je nach Kontext) auch nach der Erlaubnis.

Man muss dann allerdings mit der (meiner Meinung nach dämlichen) Antwort einiger "Spaßvögel" rechnen, die dann antworten "Also keine Ahnung, ob du kannst.", bzw. "Kannst du das denn?"

[z.B.](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/d%C3%BCrfen-vs-k%C3%B6nnen.46245/)

> "Kann ich auf die Toilette gehen?"
>
> "Ich weiß nicht, ob du das kannst, aber du kannst es mal versuchen!"

**EDIT:**

@johnl weißt in den Kommentaren richtigerweise darauf hin, dass in diversen Gesetzestexten und auch an vielen anderen Stellen die *kann*-Formulierung benutzt wird. Kann im Sinne von dürfen, also nicht unbedingt Umgangssprache sei.

Ich denke in diesen Fällen muss man genauer hinschauen, da es hier oft um Vorschriften geht und wie diese befolgt werden. Grob unterschieden wird zwischen [Muss-, Soll- und Kann-Vorschriften](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muss-,_Soll-_und_Kann-Vorschrift).

Wobei eine [Kann-Vorschrift](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kannbestimmung) eine

> Bestimmung, nach der im Einzelfall verfahren werden kann, aber nicht verfahren werden muss

ist.

Ich stimme mit @johnl dementsprechend überein: "Letztlich ist das Ganze auch einfach eine Frage der Perspektive."

Comment: +1, wobei ich nicht erkennen kann, dass das eine Frage des Registers ("Umgangssprache") ist. Man findet diese Verwendung von _können_ doch eigentlich überall. Zum Beispiel im Grundgesetz: _Der Bund **kann** den Ländern Finanzhilfen (...) gewähren._ (Art. 104c S. 1 GG) _Der Eid **kann** auch ohne religiöse Beteuerung geleistet werden._ (Art. 56 S. 2 GG) _Die Öffentlichkeit **kann** ausgeschlossen werden._ (Art. 44 I 2 GG) Letztlich ist das Ganze auch einfach eine Frage der Perspektive.