# Begriff für einleitende Fragen wie "Kann ich dich mal was fragen?"

Tags: single-word-request

Es gibt eine besondere Gruppe von Fragen, die das eigentliche Gespräch verzögern und eine Antwort erfordern, bevor die eigentliche Frage formuliert wird bzw. mit dem eigentlichen Gespräch begonnen wird. Wie bereits im Titel erwähnt, kann es sich dabei um folgenden Dialog handeln:

> A: Hallo B, kann ich dich mal was fragen?
>   B: ... ja?
>   A: Okay, also ....

Gerade in Chats findet man häufig auch (hier gleich doppelt)

> A: Hey, bist du da?
>   B: jo
>   A: Okay, ich habe da mal eine Frage, kann ich sie dir stellen?
>   B: jo
>   A: Okay, also...

Ich kann mich erinnern, dass ich für diese Art von Fragen mal einen gesonderten Begriff gelesen habe, allerdings nicht mehr, wie dieser heißt. **Ich meine keine rhetorischen Fragen**. Der Begriff, den ich suche, war ein anderer. (Zumal rhetorische Frage auch ohnehin nicht passend wäre).

Ich habe bereits das DWDS nach *frage durchsucht, bin aber nicht fündig geworden. *Scheinfrage* kommt dem recht Nahe, aber ich meine, ich suche eine anderes Wort. Falls jemand einen Artikel findet, der explizit sowas als Scheinfrage bezeichnet, bin ich allerdings auch zufrieden.

Comment: Ein ähnlicher Fall liegt vor, wenn jemand seine Absicht zu fragen ankündigt:"Ich möchte etwas fragen". Mögliche Entgegnung: "Wenn Sie nur etwas fragen *möchten*, dann überlegen Sie es sich noch mal. Und wenn Sie sich dann sicher sind, dass Sie fragen wollen, tun Sie es - fragen Sie."

Comment: Trotzdem lustig: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7fGk.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In der Form deiner Beispiele sind dies [Einstiegsfragen](https://www.landsiedel-seminare.de/coaching-welt/wissen/coaching-methoden/fragetechniken.html). Mit diesen

> wird versucht den Beginn des Gesprächs möglichst wenig offensiv und natürlich zu gestalten. Sie sollen sympathisch und ungezwungen wirken.

Bzw wenn man so will [Entscheidungsfragen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsfrage).

> Entscheidungsfragen sind die Fragen, auf die man nur mit „ja“ oder mit „nein“ antworten kann, und gehören damit zu den [geschlossene Fragen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragetechnik#Geschlossene_Fragen).

Dass die in den Beispielen genannten Fragen evtl. missverständlich formuliert sind behandelt der Thread [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen “dürfen” und “können”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55684/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-d%C3%BCrfen-und-k%C3%B6nnen/55688#55688)

Davon ab empfinde ich die Frage "bist du da?" im zweiten Beispiel innnerhalb eines Chats nicht als überflüssig. Gerade bei asynchroner Chat-Kommunikation kann man nie sicher sein, ob die andere Person im Moment wirklich anwesend ist.

Comment: Die Frage "bist du da?" ist hier insofern überflüssig, dass man auch direkt fragen kann. Kommt eine Antwort, so ist die Person das, kommt keine Antwort, ist die Person nicht da.

Comment: "Kann ich dich was fragen?" ist offener als eine Entscheidungsfrage in Reinform. Legitime, sinnvolle und zumindest meinerseits auch häufige Antworten sind z.B. "Ja, aber nicht jetzt" oder "In 5 Minuten?"

Comment: @infinitezero: Dass man das (und die Antwortbereitschaft) aus der (Nicht-)Antwort ablesen stimmt zwar, aber es macht die Frage nicht immer überflüssig. Spätestens, wenn es mehrere Leute gibt, die die eigentliche Frage beantworten können, die aber nicht da sind und wenn die Antwort länger braucht. Wenn da die eigentliche Frage steht, vertüdeln ggf. x Leute später, wenn sie wieder online sind, ihre Zeit mit Antworten, die längst bekannt sind. Steht da "Bist du da" reicht ein sekundenschnelles "jetzt, ja" und "Danke, hat sich erledigt"

Answer (score 1):

Vorewg: ich weiß auch keinen Begriff speziell für diese Fragen.
Hier auf Stackexchange würde man sie aber als **Metafragen** bezeichnen.

---

Es handelt sich m.E. nicht um Scheinfragen, denn es gibt mehrere sinnvolle und auch übliche Antwortmöglichkeiten. Die Antwort transportiert also Information.

[mtwde](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56497/5459) identifiziert sie als Einstiegsfragen, also Fragen, die einen freundlichen Gesprächsbeginn erzeugen.
Das ist aber nur dann der Fall, wenn die Antwort "ja, schieß los" ist.

M. E. ist eine wichtige Funktion dieser Fragen, dass sie das Gespräch organisieren: klären, ob und wann das Gespräch stattfinden kann und ggf. wie lange es dauern darf.

Im ersten Dialog könnte B auch antworten

- > B: Nein

  -> dann wurde die Information, dass kein Gespräch stattfindet, schneller ausgetauscht, als es ggf. dauert, die eigentliche Frage überhaupt auszusprechen oder einzutippen.
- > B: ja, aber nicht jetzt *oder* In 5 Minuten? *oder* Reicht morgen?

  -> Hier hat eine Terminabsprache stattgefunden.
- Ähnlich kann auch der Rahmen für das Gespräch begrenzt werden:

  > B: Ich hab aber nur 10 Minuten.

Sie sind daher auch **Informationsfragen** (nach der von mtwde verlinkten Liste von Fragekategorien). Hier auf Stackexchange würde man von **Metafragen** sprechen: sie klären die Rahmenbedingungen für die eigentliche Frage.

Die verschieden sinnvollen Antwortmöglichkeiten zeigen auch, dass es sich in der Praxis um **halboffene Fragen** handelt.

Weiterhin "warnen" diese Fragen den Befragten (meist implizit*), dass das Gespräch langwierig/komplex/schwierig ist - sonst wäre eine solches organisatorisches Vorgeplänkel nicht nötig.
Auch wenn hier eine Aussage als Frage verkleidet ist, würde ich nicht soweit gehen, sie deshalb als rhetorische Frage einzuordnen. Dafür ist der echte fragende Anteil zur Gesprächsorganisation zu groß.

---

* manchmal auch explizit:

> A: Hallo B, kann ich dich mal was fragen?
>   B: ... ja?
>   A: Dauert aber
>   B: Schiess' los, ich hab Zeit *oder auch* Dann lieber morgen. Um 8?